# Conditional within pipe and summarise not finding column name

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble including a conditional in my pipe. In my code, I am applying a function to data and, based on if there are any positive results, summarising the data. If there are no positive results, I need the output to be an "NA".

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-tibble(
  lab1=c(rep("cat", 5), rep("carrot", 5), rep("granite", 5)),
  lab2=c(rep("animal", 5), rep("vegetable", 5), rep("mineral", 5)),
  res=c(9.90, 10.90, 11.20, 8.70, 10.10, 9.66, 13.00, 8.88, 9.33, 8.77, 7, 7, 7,  7, 7)
)

TestSameVal<-function(d){
  if (length(unique(d$res))==1){
    return(TRUE)} else return(FALSE)
}

 result<-
  df%>%
  group_by(lab1, lab2)%>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(all_sameval=map(data, TestSameVal))%>% #Returns TRUE if all measurements for a given variable are the same value
  unnest(all_sameval)%>%
  filter(all_sameval==T)%>% #Filter on only those variables with the same value
  unnest(data)%>%
  select(-all_sameval)%>%
  {if (length(.$res)>0) summarise(rep_val=mean(res)) else T=NA}
#If there are any results where all_sameval is TRUE, summarise the results. Otherwise, assign NA
```

The code runs fine up through select(-all_sameval). I am receiving the following error, arising from the `summarise` content:

`Error in mean(res) : object 'res' not found`

Additionally, when I run the following code, it works just fine:

```
df%>%
  group_by(lab1, lab2)%>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(all_sameval=map(data, TestSameVal))%>% 
  unnest(all_sameval)%>%
  filter(all_sameval==T)%>% 
  unnest(data)%>%
  select(-all_sameval)%>%
  summarise(rep_val=mean(res))
```

I realize I could handle this using a conditional outside of the pipe, but I'd rather keep it streamlined if possible. Really the thing that's driving me up the wall is that this code was working fine yesterday. I've tried updating all my packages and restarting R.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `{if (length(.$res)>0) {. %>% summarise(rep_val=mean(res))} else NA}`. The IF interrupts the pipe, you need to pass it along again

Comment: That was close! It didn't quite work, but `{if (length(select(.,lab1)%>%pull())>0) summarise(., rep_val=mean(res)) else T=NA}` did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's code, we can wrap the `.` within the `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
   group_by(lab1, lab2)%>%
   nest()%>%
   mutate(all_sameval=map(data, TestSameVal))%>% #Returns TRUE if all measurements for a given variable are the same value
   unnest(all_sameval)%>%
   filter(all_sameval==T)%>% #Filter on only those variables with the same value
   unnest(data)%>%
   select(-all_sameval)%>%
   {if (length(.$res)>0) {.} %>% 
        summarise(rep_val=mean(res)) else T=NA}
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   lab1 [1]
#  lab1    lab2    rep_val
#  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#1 granite mineral       7
```

We could avoid creating the column 'all_sameval' if we return with `map_lgl` as a logical vector within `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    group_by(lab1, lab2)%>%
    nest() %>% 
    filter(map_lgl(data, TestSameVal)) %>% 
    unnest(data) %>% 
    summarise(rep_val = mean(res))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   lab1 [1]
#  lab1    lab2    rep_val
#  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#1 granite mineral       7
```

---

If the intention is to `filter` out the groups with only a single unique value for 'res' and get the `mean`

```
df %>%
     group_by(lab1, lab2) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(res) > 1 & !all(is.na(res))) %>% 
     summarise(res = mean(res, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't address my question -- I need the conditional statement. There are circumstances when there are no repeated values, and those need to get an NA assigned.

Comment: @aleoconn can you show your expected output.  Do you want to filter out groups where the 'res' is unique?

Comment: I have edited to clarify the main point as the question. As I said, I can get the summary just fine. It's the conditional that's giving me trouble.

Comment: @aleoconn regarding your code, it needs a simple fix.  Updated the solution